# CharlesのMac OS X Proxyの機能でリダイレクト応答を全てモニタする方法

Tags: network

Mac OSX ElCapitan + Safariの環境なのですが、Charlesでリダイレクト応答の通信をモニタする方法ってありませんか？
例えば以下のURLにアクセスすると、httpsの通信のログしか残りません。

http://twitter.com/

[image: httpsの通信だけがキャプチャされる]

curlコマンドを使うとわかるのですが、実際には301応答が一度返ってきています。

```
$ curl http://twitter.com -v
* Rebuilt URL to: http://twitter.com/
*   Trying 104.244.42.65...
* Connected to twitter.com (104.244.42.65) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: twitter.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< content-length: 0
< date: Thu, 28 Jul 2016 04:20:38 GMT
< location: https://twitter.com/
< server: tsa_a
< set-cookie: guest_id=v1%3A146967963885084115; Domain=.twitter.com; Path=/; Expires=Sat, 28-Jul-2018 04:20:38 UTC
< x-connection-hash: 7b3c31f2a72dd067f4d7ea5c2d73aab0
< x-response-time: 3
<
* Connection #0 to host twitter.com left intact
```

Charlesの設定を色々探してみたのですが、この通信ログはCharlesでは確認できませんでした。
詳しい方いたら是非教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HSTS と呼ばれる仕組みがあります。
HTTPではなくHTTPSで通信するように、Webサイトからブラウザに伝える仕組みです。
http://blog.cybozu.io/entry/6096

上記のサイトにもありますが、さらに Preloaded HSTS という仕組みがあり、
ブラウザは事前にHSTSが有効なサイトを取得しています。
https://www.chromium.org/hsts

> HSTS is supported in Google Chrome, Firefox, **Safari**, ...

SafariもPreload HSTSが有効になっており、twitterのURLも登録されていますので、
http://twitter.com にアクセスしてもブラウザ内部で https://twitter.com に変換されてしまいます。
このため、http://twitter.com へのアクセスがCharlesに記録されません。